# Globally replace Vi with Vim on Fedora

Tags: fedora, vim, vi

On Debian-based systems the alternatives system handles both the `vi` and `vim` executable. So if `vim` is installed and you execute `vi`, you also get `vim`, which I find very nice, because I absolutely hate classic `vi`.

On Fedora 17 "Beefy Miracle", the alternatives system obviously doesn't handle none of the two. But there is a profile file in `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh` which adds a shell alias to make `vi` execute `vim`. For some reason it does not do that for system users, including root.

But even if I set up an alias for all users manually, when I call `sudo vi` I'm starting classic `vi` instead of `vim`. That's probably because sudo doesn't start a shell or profile files are only executed in interactive shell sessions.

What I'm looking for now is a way to uninstall classic `vi` completely to make a symlink that even survives system updates. How can I remove classic `vi` but not `vim` on Fedora 17? Or is there even a better way?

**Update**: With `yum provides vi` I found out that `vi` is provided by the package `vim-minimal`. But I can't simply remove it because it automatically removes the package `sudo` with it. Even if I do remove it, and try to install `sudo` again afterwards, `vim-minimal` is then again installed as dependency.

**Update**: As requested, output of `rpm -qf /usr/bin/vi`:

```
vim-minimal-7.3.444-1.fc17.x86_64
```

And `ls -l /usr/bin/vi`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 782248 13. Feb 2012  /usr/bin/vi
```

Comment: `rm /usr/bin/vi; ln -s /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi`. Not an answer because I would personally find a better way (or type vim if I wanted vim).

Comment: @jordanm I meant exactly this when I asked to make a symlink survive an update. How do you ensure the link doesn't get overwritten when `vim-minimal` package is updated?

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/vi` a symlink (to what) or a regular file on Fedora? If a regular file, from what package?

Comment: @Gilles I don't understand your question.

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/vi` and `rpm -qf /usr/bin/vi`.

Comment: @Gilles Updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `vi` is Vim, but invoked as `vi`, so it enters historical compatibility mode. The recommended action is that if you want to run Vim and not vi, run `vim` and not `vi`. However, if you want `vi` to always run Vim on every account on the system, override it in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
cat >/usr/local/bin/vi <<\EOF
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/vim "$@"
EOF
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/vi
```

Comment: That's actually a very nice idea.

Comment: It even works by simply making a symlink with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vim /usr/local/bin/vi`. But you have to add `/usr/local/bin` to the left-most side of the `Defaults secure_path="…"` configuration in `visudo`, else the symlink won't be found.

Comment: I think there are some typos in the syntax here.  Did you mean `cat >/usr/local/bin/vi` (not `cat >/usr/local/bin`)?  Did you mean `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/vi` (not `.../vim`)?

Comment: To pick it up with root's default PATH, create the symlink at `/usr/local/sbin/vi`.

Comment: It is never a good idea to overwrite a system binary. It is better to create an alias for things like that.

Comment: @AdelM. “It is never a good idea to overwrite a system binary.” Which is why my answer doesn't say to do this. It shows how to put your preferred version ahead in the command search path. An alias wouldn't work when `vi` is invoked by a program other than an interactive shell.

Answer (score 6):

`# echo 'alias vi="vim"' >> /etc/bashrc'`
or `# alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/bin/vim 900`

Comment: And doesn't that get erased when the `vim-minimal` package is updated?

Comment: create an alias on `.bashrc` is a good pratice...to me @llua gave a good answer

Answer (score 1):

FYI recent fedora (at least since 18) installs that alias gobally in `/etc/profile.d` once `vim-enchanced` is installed.